# Unity3D text and buttons not showing in iOS and Android

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity3d-ui

I have built a simple game using Unity3D v. 5.4. When I tried to deploy it on iOS and Android devices, the text views and the buttons I use in the game are not shown at all, although the button's action is taken and reacts correctly.

Here is the text and button settings:

[image]

[image]

What may be the problem? I have tried to change the font and the same issue happens.

Comment: to be clear, you certainly have a CANVAS right?  (1) click add canvas (2) select **"scale with screen size"** (basically ALWAYS use that)  (3) only then click "add button" UNDER the canvas

Comment: @JoeBlow: yea, I have a canvas and it is set to "scale with screen size"

Comment: Have you checked whether your UI object's anchoring is correct?

Answer (score 1):

In this case I set always the canvas to "**scale with screen size**", I move the **anchors** marks until the borders limits of the UI object and I set his **RectTransform parameters** (in the inspector) as:

**Pos X = 0, Pos Y = 0, Pos Z = 0, Width = 0, Height = 0**

In this way you will always get the same UI proportions in all mobile devices.